# How to check if json object is exists in json file using java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to check if `score` object exists in the following json document

```
{
  "date": "2019-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",

  "doc_count": 3,

  "score": {
    "value": 100
  }
}
```

Comment: are you willing to use a JSON library, if yes do you have a preference?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. [Edit] it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON library to parse your JSON string into a `Map`, then check if your map contains the `score` key.

Using Gson

```
Map map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
```

Using Jackson

```
Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

Then:

```
boolean containsScore = map.containsKey("score");
```

Comment: @Deadpool sure, thanks!

Comment: check my answer and thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is also working:

```
     JsonElement score = json.get("score");

        if (score != null && !score.isJsonNull() ) {

     //do implementation

}
```

Comment: what is the class of your json object?